# BaseAdapter causing ListView to go out of order when scrolled

Tags: android, listview

I'm having problems with some BaseAdapter code that I adapted from a book. I've been using variations of this code all over the place in my application, but only just realized when scrolling a long list the items in the ListView become jumbled and not all of the elements are displayed.

It's very hard to describe the exact behavior, but it's easy to see if you take a sorted list of 50 items and start scrolling up and down.

```
class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Contact> mContacts;

    public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        mContacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mContacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.groups_item, null);
            TextView label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.groups_item_title);
            label.setText(mContacts.get(position).getName());
            label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.groups_item_subtitle);
            label.setText(mContacts.get(position).getNumber());
        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are only putting data in the `TextView` widgets when they are first created. You need to move these four lines:

```
        TextView label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.groups_item_title);
        label.setText(mContacts.get(position).getName());
        label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.groups_item_subtitle);
        label.setText(mContacts.get(position).getNumber());
```

to be after the `if`/`else` block and before the method return, so you update the `TextView` widgets whether you are recycling the row or creating a fresh one.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the ListView only contains at most the number of Views necessary to fill the screen?

Comment: @Mr. Ambiguous: More or less. It may cache a couple to be able to react quickly to scroll requests. However, in a `ListView` with UI space for 10 rows and an `Adapter` of 1,000 rows, the number of `Views` will be far closer to 10 than 1,000. Probably like 12 or 14. That's the point of row recycling with `convertView`, so Android does not have to create (and later GC) a whole mess of row widgets.

Answer (score 5):

To further clarify the answer of CommonsWare, here is some more info:

The *li.inflate* operation (needed here for parsing of the layout of a row from XML and creating the appropriate View object) is wrapped by an *if (convertView == null)* statement for efficiency, so the inflation of the same object will not happen again and again every time it pops into view.

HOWEVER, the other parts of the getView method are used to set other parameters and therefore should NOT be included within the *if (convertView == null){ }... else{ }* statement.

In many common implementation of this method, some textView label, ImageView or ImageButton elements need to be populated by values from the list[position], using *findViewById* and after that *.setText* or *.setImageBitmap* operations. 
These operations must come after *both* creating a view from scratch by inflation *and* getting an existing view if not null (e.g. on a refresh).

Another good example where this solution is applied for a ListView ArrayAdapter appears in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874639/978329