# Listview with Listview as an items, the inner listview is not fully visible

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to have a listview with listviews as items, only the first row is visible in the inner listview(listview item).

My listview Item xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/numbers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have [scrollable view in other scrollable views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/1051783). The same happens if you put a list view in a `ScrollView`. 
For your purpose, why not implement multiple view items type? Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664100/different-row-layouts-in-listview) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row).

Comment: Or, use `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: I dont need the inner listview to scroll

Comment: Then why did you add it? Why not use some sort of `View` or `ViewGroup`?

Comment: @gunar I have used a view in the end with around 40 for each view

Answer (score 1):

inside of one scrollable view another won't scroll..
call this method after u set adapter and pass your listview..

```
private void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
int totalHeight = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
listItem.measure(0, 0);
totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight
+ (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.requestLayout();
}
```

http://kirukkupayal-mani.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-expandable-listview-inside.html