# ListView inflating issue

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, recycle

I'm building an sms app, and need to show the view according to Incoming/Outgoing sms.
I'm facing the following issue, in my **getView(..)** I need to know if it's Incoming/Outgoing and then to show the following:

Incoming VIEW

[image: Incoming VIEW]

Outgoing VIEW

[image]

But i can't think of a way to implement 1 view to handle this (because of the recycling in listview).

I thought of using setLayoutDirection in a LinearLayout, or maybe removeViews and then add them in correct position. Can you please assist me with the best way with the less performance?

Thanks very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items. check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the getViewType method in order to precise how many kind of rows you listview has.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665523/2178259).

Comment: Yeah i've been thinking of this, but isn't this option has high performance? also, second time the view already inflated with RTL and its not null and I need to change it to LTR, this isn't help me much

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know if it has high performance ! I don't think also that there is another solution to have different rows in a list, without overriding this method ! Just respect the recycling pattern and let android do the rest for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how to achieve it with good performance: http://adilsoomro.blogspot.fi/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html

Comment: Not that good, it's only changing the background, i have several views which need layout direction change also.

Comment: You can build your list item that you just need to adjust the gravity/text/image for recycled view

Comment: That's not possible, i need to change the direction of all view, not just left/right gravity and bg image...

Comment: I don't understand how it's not possible, RelativeLayout as ViewGroup and alignParentLeft/alignParentRight with toLeftOf and toRightOf? Can you post better image of your cases?