# getting images from external sd card folder and displaying them in a list

Tags: android

Im trying to get images from a particular folder inside the external `SD card` and trying to show them inside a list when im running the app. No error provided, nothing happens. Just a blank page any suggestion.

i'm getting the list of images with the extension but how can i view the images!

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        File file = new File("/sdcard/external_sd/folder_name/");

        File imageList[] = file.listFiles();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        for(int i=0;i<imageList.length;i++)
        {
            Log.e("Image: "+i+": path", imageList[i].getAbsolutePath());

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageList[i].getAbsolutePath());

            images.add(b);

        }
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,imageList));
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Bitmaps are decoded correctly?
Consider using new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"folder name") as well.

Comment: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,imageList));
I'm getting the list of the images with the extension how can i make them appear ? as an image

Comment: Tony the Pony here is the listView ..

Answer (score 0):

You will face with `OutOfMemory` exception, if you use your code to load image. Try using the method below to load image correctly. After that you can populate your `ListView`.

```
private static final int IMG_BUFFER_LEN = 16384;
// R.drawable.ic_default - default drawable resource, if we cannot load drawable from provided file
// R.dimen.list_icon_size - size in dp of ImageView inside of ListView (for example, 40dp)

private Drawable extractMediaIcon(String filePath) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    if (options.outWidth < 0 || options.outHeight < 0 || (options.outWidth * options.outHeight == 0)) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_default);
    }

    final int targetHeight = dp2px((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.list_icon_size));
    final int targetWidth = targetHeight;

    final boolean isScaleByHeight =
        Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);

    if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= IMG_BUFFER_LEN) {
        // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired dimensions
        final double sampleSize = isScaleByHeight
                ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
        options.inSampleSize =
                (int) Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(
                        Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
    }

    // Do the actual decoding
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[IMG_BUFFER_LEN];

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_default);
    }

    final double imageFactor = (double) bitmap.getWidth() / bitmap.getHeight();
    final double targetFactor = (double) targetWidth / targetHeight;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmap,
            targetFactor > imageFactor ? bitmap.getWidth() * targetHeight / bitmap.getHeight() : targetWidth,
            targetFactor > imageFactor ? targetHeight : bitmap.getHeight() * targetWidth / bitmap.getWidth(),
            false);

    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Comment: StenaviN i tried your method didn't work for me i need to predefine the file path..

Comment: Ofcourse, call `extractMediaIcon(...)` method, providing path to image file on sdcard and get back `Drawable`

Comment: StenaviN can u provide me with a setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,..)); what should be in second argument in your code! i can't find a way to show the images can you help me out

Comment: I don't recommend using standard adapters. I always use custom ones and perform optimization via "holder" pattern. Learn more [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3123193/716075). There are a lot of examples.

Comment: i managed to get all the images that are located in my gallery folder how can i filter the content in order to get only a the content of a specific folder any ideas i am using this  

cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
   
   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // Which columns to return
   
   null,
    //return all rows
    null,
   
   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);