# problems using GridView with soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My program's main panel is a GridView .But when I touch an item of it  and type in some words by soft keyboard,every item of the GridView changes its position.Then exit the program ,it amazes me that the items  is just fine when I launch the program again ,
  Any suggestions?
    Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning Android and I had the same problem.  I found the answer here:

[BaseAdapter causing ListView to go out of order when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121153/baseadapter-causing-listview-to-go-out-of-order-when-scrolled)

The problem was with the standard implementation of the image adapter.