# How to handle **Grid View** on configuration change?

Tags: android, gridview, configuration

I am using a grid view in my app's activity. Each grid view row contains three check boxes which can be set to selected/ not selected based on what user wants to query from database. The activity also includes an *editText* which causes an **onScreenKeyboard** to appear every time activity starts and here I am having problem. *OnScreenKeyboard*, when appears disturbs gridview and some of its **checkboxes** simply disappear. My idea was to refresh grid view every time configuration changes. I tried handling this by returning an object through **onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()**. Object contains an array list to populate my *gridview* rows with but **onCreate()** when I use **getLastNonConfigurationInstance()** to retrieve returned object it shows null. Can anyone please suggest me that how to handle this issue or if there is any other approach available by which I can make my *gridView*  behave normal on configuration change. Following is the code and i want to make it clear I have added **keyboardHidden** configuration change in manifest file but when key board appears it sometimes don't trigger **onConfigurationChanged()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.failureselection);
    findLocalWidgets(); //Initializes Layout Objects

    if(configchanged){
                    //Re populate grid view
                        customDataGridRows = (ArrayList<CustomGridViewRow>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
                        dgvwFailures.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this,
                                customDataGridRows));

                                configchanged = false;
                      }else{
                            fillFailuresList(customDataGridRows);
                            dgvwFailures.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this,
                                    customDataGridRows));
                    }

    }


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.failureselection);

    configchanged = true;
}


@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {

    return customDataGridRows;
}

private boolean fillFailuresList(
        ArrayList<CustomGridViewRow> customDataGridRows) {
    boolean isFilled = false;
    try {
        // Adding Failures data
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "Hood", false,
                "Assembly Defect", false, "Masking Poor"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "Floor", false,
                "Forget Work", false, "Assembly Defect"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "Grill", false,
                "Incorrect Assembly", false, "Bad Company"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false,
                "R Right Frame", false, "Interference", false,
                "Fix Large Effort"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "R Left Frame",
                false, "Leakage", false, "High Incidence"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "R Frame",
                false, "Dirt", false, "Recurrence"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false,
                "Outside R Frame", false, "Decal", false, "Checking"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false,
                "F Right Frame", false, "Other", false, "Foreign Body"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "F Left Frame",
                false, "", false, "Not Caulking"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "F Frame",
                false, "", false, "Painting Defect"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false,
                "Outsie F Frame", false, "", false, "Other"));
        customDataGridRows.add(new CustomGridViewRow(false, "", false, "",
                false, ""));

        // Populating Failures grid view
//      dgvwFailures.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this,
//              customDataGridRows));

        isFilled = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return isFilled;

}
```

Comment: It really helps, if you put code samples in your question. This way, users might copy and paste it in a project, to actually see what's going on. Consider doing that, to generate more valuable answers for your questions

Comment: Hope new edit will help you understand my problem. Thank you

Comment: Why dont you simply prevent the keyboard from appearing when the activity starts ? I am sure you will get the code if you google a little more.

Comment: The problem and solution are both here:<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121153/baseadapter-causing-listview-to-go-out-of-order-when-scrolled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A couple of options:**

1. [How to prevent Custom Views from losing state across screen orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes/3542895#3542895) for your `CustomGridViewRow`.
2. Create a method in your Adapter and put the values in a bundle and restore it on create using the `savedInstanceState`

Tip:
Remove any `<requestFocus />` from your EditText layout. Although Android will set focus to the first focusable view.

Another hack: [How to remove focus without setting focus to another control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117967/how-to-remove-focus-without-setting-focus-to-another-control)

Answer (score 2):

If your onConfigurationChanged is not called always, consider adding

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in your Manifest. This will also trigger the onConfigurationChanged call, when the orientation of the device changes. Also, i'm not sure with the setContentView inside your onCOnfigurationChanged. Good luck

Comment: The configchanges tag has already been added in application's manifest with the entries     android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|Orientation" but still its not triggering __onconfigurationChanged()__ when keyboard appears but works fine for orientation changes.

Comment: I guess, you also want the call when the SoftKeyboard is shown/hidden. The keyBoardHidden attribute is only for a physical keyboard. Try the solution from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown

Comment: try adding screenSize attribute as well...this has changed with 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing this, you can over write `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)` & in this `bunde`  save all the present state of all UI components(like `bundle.putBoolean("check_box_1", true)`). When there will any configuration change Android system will call this method.

After configuration change when the system will recreate your activity by calling `onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)` the same `Buldle` instance will be provided so this time `saveInstanceState` is not `null`. From this `Bundle` extract previously saved values(like `saveInstanceState.getBoolean("check_box_1")`) & set those to respective fields.

This is the satndard way to handle this & because of this `onCreate()` have a `Bundle` as input parameter.